# Entrega de produtos digitais de forma segura em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download

Fala pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em que o cliente pode efetuar a compra e recebe um link para download do produto. O sistema possui uma área de cadastros no qual é possível fazer o upload do ZIP para uma pasta dentro do servidor. Porém, gostaria de descobrir como faço para que os downloads sejam seguros, ou seja, outras pessoas não possam baixar pelo mesmo arquivo. Pensei em criar um script que duplica este arquivo original para uma pasta publica e renomeia este arquivo para algo aleatorio, do tipo j45287yudfre4587.zip sempre que houver uma compra e libera um link para que o comprador possa baixar, depois de algum tempo ele apagar automaticamente essa copia. Não sei se é o jeito correto ou se existe um jeito mais profissional de fazer.

Comment: Anderson te recomendo a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona a comunidade, primeiramente tente fazer algo, depois faça a pergunta expondo sua dúvida e ou problema.

Comment: OK, vamos considerar como resolvido, iniciarei o desenvolvimento e volto a postar. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<a href="download.php?id=id-do-arquivo-ou-alguma-coisa-que-o-identifique">Download</a>
```

Aí nesse arquivo "**download.php**" você força o download do arquivo informado..

Link href em php:

```
<a href='download.php?id={$row['file_name']}'>
```

Php download.php:

```
<?php
  // Verifique se um ID foi passado
    if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {
        // Pegue o ID$id
        $file_name= ($_GET['ID']);
        // Certifique-se de que o ID é de fato uma ID válida
    if($file_name == NULL) {
        die('O nome é inválido!');
    }
    else {
        // Conecte-se ao banco de dados
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', "", 'db_name');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Falha na conexão do MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
         // Obtenha as informações do arquivo
        $query = "
            SELECT `type`, `file_name`, `size`, `data`
            FROM `arquivos`
            WHERE `file_name` = {$file_name}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        if($result) {
            // Verifique se o resultado é válido
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Obter a linha
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                header("Content-Type: ".$row['type']);
                header("Content-Length: ".$row['size']);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment"); 
                // Imprimir dados
                echo $row['data'];
            }
            else {
                echo 'Erro! Não existe nenhum arquivo com essa ID.';
            }
            // Livre os recursos do mysqli
            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            // Se houver um erro ao executar a consulta
            echo "Erro! Falha na consulta: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        // Cechar a conexão do banco de dados
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    // Se nenhuma ID passou
    echo 'Erro! Nenhuma ID foi aprovada.';
}
?>
```

Você pode fazer assim também:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET[id];

if ($id == "123456") {
 header('Location: http://www.site.com.br/Arquivo.rar');
  } else {
 echo "Arquivo não encontrado";
}

?>
```

Ele vai identificar o "**?id=123456**" no seu Link e vai fazer o Download Arquivo "http://www.site.com.br/Arquivo.rar" Claro, você pode colocar qualquer id, ou até mais de 1 id, dai seu código teria que ficar assim... http://www.site.com.br/download.php?id=1

```
<?php

$id = $_GET[id];

if ($id == "1") {
 header('Location: http://www.site.com.br/Arquivo1.rar');
  } elseif ($id == "2") {
 header('Location: http://www.site.com.br/Arquivo2.rar');
  } elseif ($id == "3") {
 header('Location: http://www.site.com.br/Arquivo3.rar');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Definindo o banco de dados

Já que você está utilizando banco de dados, da para fazer algo mais facil de dar manutenção. Imagine uma tabela chamada arquivos:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|nome_arquivo varchar(100) not null unique||
|data_fim date                             |
|usuario_id  varchar (200)                 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

E uma tabela usuarios (não vai ser necessario um sistema de autenticação completo, mas pode ser expandido):

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|id integer not null primary key auto_increment|
|nome varchar(100) not null unique             |
|token  varchar (200) not null unique          |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

## Mini sistema de controle de acesso à arquivos

Para não precisar criar um sistema de login (na pergunta não fica claro se você quer isso (mas pode ser expandido para atender essa necessidade)) toda vez que o usuario for enviar um novo arquivo, ele primeiro irá gerar um token. Então podemos imaginar um simples formmulario para fazer isso, chamemos de **usuario_token.php** o arquivo que contem esse formulario:

```
<form action="gerar_token.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Nome de usuário</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Obter token">
    </div>
</form>
```

No arquivo **gerar_token.php** teria que inserir um novo registro na tabela **usuarios**, onde seriam inseridos os campos nome do usuario e um token para acesso posterior. Ficando assim:

```
<?php
$usuario_nome = null;
$usuario_token = null;

if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    //você pode ler mais sobre uniqid na referencia do php
    // em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php
    //basicamente ela gerar um identificador unico
    //composto por caracteres alphanumericos
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $id = criarUsuario($nome, $token);

    if($id !== 0){
        $conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
        //como não tem dados vindo do formulario que precisam ser
        //colocados na consulta, não é necessario usuar prepare statement
        $resultado = $conexao->query('select nome, token from usuarios 
                        where id = ' . $id);
        $usuario = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        $usuario_nome = $usuario['nome'];
        $usuario_token = $usuario['toekn'];
    }else{
        echo 'Aconteceu algum erro ao salvar!';
        echo ' Pode ser qualquer coisa, nome de usuario duplicado, etc.';
    }
}

/**
@param string $nome nome do usuario vindo do formulario
@param string $token campo aleatorio gerado com a função uniqid()
@return mixed 0 caso o usuario usuario não possa ser salvo
                (nome de usuario duplicado, por exemplo), e se o
                for salvo com sucesso retornara o id do novo registro
                criado (auto_increment), onde id > 0 (maior que zero)
*/
function criarUsuario($nome, $token){
      //aqui você deve substituir pelos dados de acesso do seu banco
      $conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');

      //para evitar injeção de sql vamos usar prepare statement
      $statement= $conexao->prepare('insert into usuarios (nome, token) 
      values (?, ?)');

      //cada interrogação no instrução acima será representada pelo 
      //tipo (string, integer, etc) e qual valor irá receber, 
      //nesse exemplo $nome e $token
      $statement->bind_param('ss', $nome, $token);

      //e por fim executamos a instrução no banco
      $status = $statement->execute();

      //se a instrução tiver executado com sucesso, retornamos o id 
      //do novo registro criado, caso contrario retornamos 0 
      //(erro ao salvar)
      if($status === true){
          return $conexao->insert_id;
      }

      return 0;
}

/******************************************************************
Agora geramos o formulario para enviar arquivos. O formulario poderia
estar em outro arquivo, mas por simplificação vai ficar aqui mesmo.

Tambem mostramos para o usuario: seu nome de usuario e seu token
para que ele possa anota-los, para futuramente usar apenas o token para
enviar arquivos (já que é mais "dificil" de adivinhar)
******************************************************************/

//só mostra o formulario se as variaveis $usuario_nome e $usuario_token
forem diferentes de null, ou seja, foram cadastrados com sucesso
if($usuario_nome === null && $usuario_token === null){
    //encerra a execução do script (não mostrando o formulario abaixo)
    exit;
}

//caso sejam diferentes de null mostra o formulario
//veja que com o if assima foi possivel "omitir" o else
?>

<div>
    <label>
        Seu nome de usuario é:<?php echo $usuario_nome; ?>
    </label>
    <label>
        Seu token de acesso é:<?php echo $usuario_token; ?>
    </label>
</div>

<form action="salvar_arquivo.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Insira seu token de acesso</label>
        <input type="text" name="token">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Escolha um arquivo</label>
        <input type="file" name="arquivo">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Salvar</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
    </div>
</form>
```

A maioria das funções utilizados no arquivo **gerar_token.php** já estão comentadas, mas vale citar novamente [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php), [prepare statement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php), [last insert id](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php), [fetch assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) (não necessariamente em ordem).

Mas voltando à estrutura do codigo acima (**gerar_token.php**). Nesse arquivo foi criado um `if` para verificar se o formulario de cadastrar
 usuario havia sido submetido. Em seguida foi feita uma chamada à função
`cadastrarUsuario()` responsavel por inserir um novo registro na tabela
**usuarios** e retornar o id do registro inserido. O retorno dessa função
foi usado para fazer um select no banco e retornar, entre outros, o token
salvo no banco. E por fim foi exibido o formulario para enviar arquivos.
Só mais um detalhe, esse formulario (de enviar arquivos) pode ser colocado
em um arquio separado, quando o usuario já tiver sido "cadastrado". Tipo isso (arquivo enviar_arquivo.php):

```
<form action="salvar_arquivo.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Insira seu token de acesso</label>
            <input type="text" name="token">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Escolha um arquivo</label>
            <input type="file" name="arquivo">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Salvar</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
        </div>
    </form>
```

E agora só falta o codigo para salvar o arquivo enviado pelo formulario e listar os arquivos de um usuario especifico.

O arquivo **salvar_arquivo.php** fica assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
    //pode ser uma pasta fora do public do seu site
    //nesse caso esta no mesmo diretorio desse arquivo
    $diretorio_arquivos = __DIR__ . '/arquivos';
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    //cria nome de arquivo unico
    $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['name'] . uniqid(rand(), true);
    $arquivo_temporario = $_FILES['tmp_name'];

    //agora checamos se o tokem existe no banco
    if(tokenExiste($token) === true){
        $conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
        $usuario_id = $conexao("select id from usuarios where token = '" .
                  $token . "'");
        $usuario_id = $usuario_id->fetch_assoc()['id'];
        $data_fim = '2018-01-20';

        $statement = $conexao->prepare('insert into arquivos 
        (nome_arquivo, data_fim, usuario_id) values (?, ?, ?)');
        $statement->bind_param('ssi', $nome_arquivo, $data_fim, 
        $usuario_id);
        $statement->execute();

        //move o arquivo para o diretorio definitivo
        move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_temporario , 
        $diretorio_arquivos . '/' . $nome_arquivo );

        //da para fazer algumas validações, mas como seria
        //necessario fazer rollback no banco, deixo a seu criterio
        //implementar
        echo 'provavelmene arquivo!';
    }
    else{
       echo 'token invalido! Já fez o cadastro?';
    }
}

function tokenExiste($token){
    $conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
    $statement = $conexao->prepare('select token from usuarios 
                 where token = ?');
    $statement->bind_param('s', $token);
    $statement->execute();

    $statement->store_result();

    //token existe
    if($statement->num_rows == 1){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

O codigo em si está bem explicativo, mas vale ressaltar referencias para aprofundar em [move uploaded file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php), [mysqli num rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

E por fim para listar os arquivos de um usuario basta fazer um join entre as tabelas **usuarios** e **arquivos**. Então, no arquivo **listar_arquivos.php**:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="token">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['token'])){
        $arquivos = listaArquivos($_POST['token']);

        //não existem arquivos ou token invalido, encerra o script
        if(count($arquivos) < 1){
             echo 'não existem arquivos ou token invalido';
             exit;
        }

        //exibir arquivos em ul
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($arquivos as $arquivo){
            echo '<li><a href="ver.php?nome=' . $arquivo 
            . '&token=' . $_POST['token'] . '">' . $arquivo
            .'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    function listaArquivos($token){
        $conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
        $statement = $conexao->prepare('select nome_arquivo from usuarios,
        arquivos where token = ? and usuario_id = id');

        $statement->bind_param('s', $token);
        $statement->execute();

        $nome_arquivo = null;
        //armazenar o nome de todos os arquivos
        $arquivos = [];

        $statement->bind_result($nome_arquivo);

        //percorre todo o resultset da consulta acima
        while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $arquivos[] = $nome_arquivo;
        }

        return $arquivos;
    }
?>
```

E como sempre aprofunde-se em [bind result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), [fetch](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), [statement fetch](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Por fim, quando você clicar em um link da lista acima, você vai ser redirecionado para um arquivo chamado **ver.php** que receberá como parametro o nome do arquivo a ser exibido e o token de acesso. O arquivo **ver.php** fica assim:

```
<?php
$token = $_GET['token'];
$nome_arquivo = $_GET['nome'];

//se existir o token e o nome de arquivo associados a um mesmo usuario
//a função podeAcessar retorna true
if(podeAcessar($nome_arquivo, $token)){
    $diretorio_arquivos = __DIR__ . '/arquivos';

    //enviando o arquivo para o usuario
     $mime = mime_content_type($diretorio_arquivos . '/' . $nome_arquivo);
     $tamanho = filesize($diretorio_arquivos . '/' . $nome_arquivo)

     header("Content-Type: ". $mime);
     header("Content-Length: " . $tamanho);
     //retorna o conteudo do arquivo salvo no servidor
     //dependendo do tipo de mime ("extensão") o proprio navegador exibira.
     //caso não seja compativel com o render oferecido pelo navegador 
     //será baixado
     echo file_get_contents($diretorio_arquivos . '/' . $nome_arquivo);
}else{
 echo 'parece que você não pode acessar este arquivo!';
}

function podeAcessar($nome_arquivo, $token){
    $conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
    $statement = $conexao->prepare('select nome_arquivo from usuarios, 
    arquivos where token = ? and usuario_id = id and nome_arquivo = ?');

    $statement->bind_param('ss', $token, $nome_arquivo);
    $statement->execute();

    $statement->store_result();

    //pode acessar
    if($statement->num_rows == 1){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

E para se aprofundar nas funções utilizadas consulte 
[mime content type](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php), [filesize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filesize.php), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) (Todos na documentação do [php](http://php.net/)).

Com isso você deve ter um sistema razoavelmente seguro, uma vez que os arquivos não estarão no diretorio publico, pois você pode criar a pasta de arquivos um diretorio acima da pasta publica (raiz do servidor), por exemplo, fazendo `echo realpath($diretorio_arquivos . '/../pastadearquivos')`. Isso permite acessar a pasta **pastadearquivo** que está fora da raiz do servidor. Além disso ainda da para evitar ataques de injeção (tanto de sql, como tentar enviar um caminho arbitrario).

Observação: podem haver erros de sintaxe (variaveis faltando letras) pois não usei o interpretador para validar os codigos acima. Mas da para ter uma ideia geral.