# Como exibir a imagem salva no banco de dados no meu codigo html

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, metaprogramação

Tenho um banco de dados mysql criado no phpmyadmin, ja salvei o caminho das imagens la, também em uma tabela imagem com id e nome(img), agora gostaria de saber como faço para exibir essas imagens nos respectivos lugares no meu codigo html... essa é uma parte do codigo onde está a imagem q vem de uma pasta

```
            <img src="img/pat.png" class="img-responsive" width="300px" height="300px" align="#"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <p> <h4><b> Restaurante Do Cardoso</b> </h4>
                <p align="justify"> />
```

ai no lugar daquele img/pat.png, gostaria de colocar o caminho da imagem que esta salva la no banco e exibir, mas nao estou conseguindo... ja crie a conexao com o banco de dados e tudo mais

Comment: Ué, você vai precisar do php para pegar os dados do banco.

Comment: sim eu que preciso do php, oque eu não sei é como fazer esse codigo quais as linhas de comandos e onde salvar

Comment: visite esse link para ver um exemplo https://imasters.com.br/artigo/3831/mysql/cadastrando-e-exibindo-imagens-diretamente-do-mysql-5/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: eu estou salvando no BD apenas os caminhos da imagem, em um campo VARCHAR e nao BLOB, ja visitei esse link e fiz tudo isso e mesmo assim não deu certo, ainda sou novo nessa parte de php e banco de dados, não sei quase nada

Comment: pra vc pegar vc precisa usar uma linguagem de programação do lado do servidor.. exemplo de uma php.. vc ja faz isso ? mostre seu codigo pra poder ajudar mais...

Comment: o meu codigo é todo em html com JS assim... <img src="img/pat.png" class="img-responsive" width="300px" height="300px" align="#"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <p> <h4><b> Restaurante Do Cardoso</b> </h4>
                <p align="justify"> />

a parte de conexao com o banco eu ja fiz, oq eu não sei fazer é a parte de exibir a imagem no html atraves de um php

Comment: eu ja desenvolvi tudo, mas vi q se começar a salvar as imagens dentro da pasta do app, vai ficar muito pesado, ai queria enviar para o banco e do banco exibir no codigo, a parte de mandar para o banco de dados as imagens eu ja fiz, atraves do caminho delas, agora só quero puxar la do banco e exibir na tela, tipo tem o nome do restaurante e embaixo a imagem eu quero essa imagem vindo diretamente do banco de dados

Comment: esse é o app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.mariano.jabukatur  todas as imagens dele esta dentro de uma pasta no mesmo arquivo e isso pesa eu queria essas imagens vindo la do banco

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução simples é criar um arquivo `.php` para manipular a exibição das suas imagens. Você pode criar a seguinte url para acesso às suas imagens: `obterImagens.php?nome=nome_da_imagem`

## Codigo html para requisição de imagens

```
<img src="obterImagens.php?nome=imagem1" class="img-responsive" 
width="300px" height="300px" align="#">

<img src="obterImagens.php?nome=imagem2" class="img-responsive" 
width="300px" height="300px" align="#">
```

## Codigo PHP para retornar uma imagem

Antes do codigo php, suponho que você tenha uma tabela no banco de dados similar a essa:

```
|nome_imagem|local_imagem|
```

Supondo que as imagens estão salvas em um diretorio no seu sistema de arquivos podemos retorna-las usando a função `file_get_contents()`.

Então, voltando para o php podemos fazer isso:

```
$nome_imagem = $_GET['nome'];
$conexao = mysqli_connect($conexao,'host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'nome_banco');
$consulta = mysqli_query('select * from imagens where nome_imagem = ' 
. "'" . $nome_imagem . "'");
//como o nome da imagem deve ser unico, apenas um registro deveria ser 
//retornado
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

//como o campo local_imagem é o caminho absoluto ou relativo para 
//a imagem fica facil acessa-la agora.
$caminho_imagem = $resultado['local_imagem'];
//suponto que você salva todas as imagens no mesmo diretorio do script
//A varaivel $resultado['local_imagem'] poderia representar 
//apenas o nome da imagem, e você poderia concatenar os dois

 $mime = mime_content_type(__DIR__ . '/' . $caminho_imagem);
 $tamanho = filesize(__DIR__ . '/' . $caminho_imagem);

 header("Content-Type: ". $mime);
 header("Content-Length: " . $tamanho);

 //e por fim você manda para o navegador
 echo file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . $caminho_imagem);
```

Essa resposta foi adaptada de uma pergunta disponivel no proprio [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265115/entrega-de-produtos-digitais-de-forma-segura-em-php/265127#265127). NO [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql) tem uma pergunta (com resposta) muito mais proxima do que você quer.

Comment: vlaeu amigo vo testar aqui e falo se deu certo

Comment: amigo devo estar fazendo algo errado, como não tenho muita experiencia nisso nao está funcionando

Comment: @MarianoRibeiro utilize a função **[mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)** para verificar qual o erro você está tendo.